# Maintain scroll position at bottom after loading images with variable dimensions

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, webview

I have a Cordova app with a chat feature that loads images from a SQLite database on the device. I have code that scrolls the chat to the bottom when it's opened, but there's a problem where chat images may not be fully loaded when this programmatic scroll happens. As a result, when the images load fully, their heights are added to the height of the messages container, causing the bottom of the container to move and therefore the chat screen is no longer scrolled to the bottom. My current solution is to use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to check for `img` nodes being added to the container. Here is a shell of what the mutation observer's callback does:

```
    const mutObsCb = function(mutationsList) {
      if (userHasScrolledChatMessages) {
        // no need to scroll down to bottom
        return;
      }
      mutationsList.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
                [].forEach.call(mutation.addedNodes, function(node) {
                    if (node.matches('.nodeWithImages')) {
                      // this message contains at least one image
                      const imgs = node.querySelectorAll('img');
                      imgs.forEach(function(img) {
                        // has image request completed even if it failed?
                        if (img.complete) {
                          scrollChatToBottom();
                        } else {
                          img.onload = function() {
                            scrollChatToBottom();
                          };
                        }
                      });
                    }
                });
              }
        })
    };
```

Essentially, if the image request has completed (by checking the [`complete`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-img-complete) attribute), I scroll to the bottom of the container, otherwise I assign a function to the image's `onload` handler and in the function I scroll the chat to the bottom.

The problem with this method is that there may be a brief but noticeable period after entering the chat when one or more images start loading (hence the scroll position changes) but are not yet fully loaded (hence the chat isn't yet scrolled to the bottom). I don't want to have this brief period, I want to enter the chat and have it scrolled to the bottom even while images load. Looking forward to your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Only show chat when it's loaded and ready? Basically you just want to hide that brief part?

Comment: Not quite. The chat has to be shown, but the chat needs to be scrolled all the way to the bottom. The loading images can change the scroll position when they finally load, and I'm trying to prevent or account for that change.